# FTP transfer server to server using SSH/command line

Tags: command-line, ssh, ftp, rsync

I have a bunch of vendors that make their FTPs available to download images of their products. Some of these guys like to put them into multiple subfolders, using the collection or style name and then sku. For example, they will make folder structure like:

```
Main folder
---> Collection A
------> Sku A
----------> SKUApicture1.jpg, SKUApicture2.jpg
------> sku B
----------> SKUBpicture1.jpg, SKUBpicture2.jpg

---> Collection B
------> Sku C
----------> SKUCpicture1.jpg, SKUCpicture2.jpg
------> sku D
----------> SKUDpicture1.jpg, SKUDpicture2.jpg
```

Until now, I have found it easiest to log onto my server via SSH, navigate to the folder I want, and then log on to my vendor's FTP, at which point I put in the user name a PW and navigate to the folder I want, and then take all the images using mget. If all (or most) of the files are in 1 folder, this is simple.

The problem is **mget** won't take and folders or subfolders, it will only take files within the given folder. In the above example, my vendor has over 10 folders and each one has 100+ subfolders, so navigating to each one isn't an option.

Also, the industry I deal in isn't tech savy, so asking their "tech people" to enable/allow **SCP**, **SFTP**, or **rsync**, etc., is likely not an option.

Downloading all the images locally and re-uploading them to my server also isn't practical, as this folder is over 10GB.

I'm looking for a command (**mget** or other) that will enable me to take ALL files and subfolders, as is, and copy straight to my server (via **SSH**).

Thanks

**NOTE:** For this particular server I tried **rsync**, but got an error telling me it wasn't compatible with that command. I doubt I have the command wrong, but if you want to post the proper way to **rsync** I'll be more then happy to try it again and provide the exact error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/
```

It should recursively get all the files from the remote ftp.

Comment: trying this now, and it seems to be working. Will report back shortly.

Comment: Is wget the key here? Meaning, if I logged in via ftp and used wget instead would it work? I believe I tried wget before (once already logged in) and it gave me an error saying the remote server didn't recognize wget

Comment: @JoshB wget will behaves like a normal browser. If you can download it with a browser, you can do it with wget.

Comment: @JoshB if the command is not installed in the server and you have root access, you can install it with `yum install wget` for Redhat based systems or `apt-get install wget` for Debian based systems.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked. I just want to clarify for anyone who sees this later: wget is the key, but you need to access it the way Tk421 posted, this way, it's your own server constantly requesting the files. If you were to access the remote server first and then request the files with wget, they remote server may not allow wget/may not be capable of utilizing it, and therefor may not be able to send the files back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lftp`](https://lftp.yar.ru/):

```
lftp -e 'mirror <remote download dir> <local download dir>' -u <username>,<pass> <host>
```

Taken from [Copying Folder Contents with Subdirectories Over FTP](https://serverfault.com/q/477286/168875).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SFTP?  You said that FTP works how you want it to work,  and SFTP works the exact same way.  Your FTP client with SFTP support behaves the exact same way but it's using SSH to connect.

Comment: The other server won't allow log on with SFTP